# error with migrate refresh

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am getting this error when trying to run: php artisan migrate:refresh:

```
Rolled back: 2016_02_16_114444_create_posts_table
Rolled back: 2016_01_20_234538_expectations
Rolled back: 2016_01_20_200616_expectation_profile
Rolled back: 2015_12_22_111958_create_profiles_table
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table


  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                          
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'follower  
  _id' (SQL: alter table `follower_followee` add `follower_id` int unsigned no  
  t null, add `followee_id` int unsigned not null)                              

  [PDOException]                                                                
  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'follower  
  _id'
```

This is the migration the error refers to:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class FollowerFollowee extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('follower_followee', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned(); // follower id number,must be positive.
            $table->integer('followee_id')->unsigned(); // followee id number,must be positive.
            $table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            //The 'follower_id' column references to the 'id' column in a 'users' table.
            //When a user is deleted in the parent column ('follower_id'), then also the user in 'id' ('users') is deleted. 
            $table->foreign('followee_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()

{
    Schema::dropIfExists('follower_followee');
    }
}
```

when trying to run : composer dump-autoload - it returns only this:

```
Generating autoload files
```

I honestly can't identify where's that duplication appears. Any help would be lovely.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you are rolling back everything so try to delete everything in your database then run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: This is possibly the result of one migration's `down` method not implementing the correct query to rollback a migration. Are you sure you didn't create the `follower_id` in another migration which failed to remove it on rollback, and now you're trying to recreate it with this migration. In any case, you should check the database and see if the current state of your tables are as you'd expect them, as you might need to make some manual adjustments for your migrations to work again.

Comment: @PeterPan666 that's what I did a few times. and when trying to update some migration and running php artisan migrate:refresh it gives me the same error.

@Bogdan I have changed the migration's drop method to this:
`public function down()
    
{        Schema::table('follower_followee', function (Blueprint $table) {

    Schema::dropIfExists('follower_followee');
    }
}`

Comment: And now it gives me a new error when trying to run migrate:refresh.
It now pointing to other migration (users):
Code is to long for here so here's an external link to it:
http://paste.ofcode.org/59GGkDpFbhsVrSKdVUY7Jg

Comment: Why doing `dropIfExists` instead of simply `drop`?

Comment: @PeterPan666 check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the tables' down method mentioned in the error (in the terminal) to this:

```
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('follower_followee');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
}
}
```

With this I can delete parent tables without errors for foreign keys.

did it for the tables only. then removed manually all my tables from db and then ran php artisan migrate and php artisan migrate:refresh without any errors. 
Thanks for whoever tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating column 'follower_id' and 'followee_id' twice:

```
$table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned();

$table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

The first statement is redundant in both cases and causes the mentioned error.

-- Edit: Reading the docs I realize am wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's self answer to this question is actually not the right way to go about it. You should be instead dropping the foreign key relationship established so that you don't run into this error:

```
public function down(){
    Schema::table('follower_followee', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('followee_id_users_foreign');
        $table->dropForeign('follower_id_users_foreign');
    });
}
```

If the name of the foreign is incorrect, you can find the proper name in PhpMyAdmin (if in use) under table->structure->relationships

Comment: Unfortunately I'm encountring an error when running php artisan migrate:refresh with your down method:
https://jpst.it/FRR6